# List<Image> Image ... "Image.Add()" error: has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

```
AllProjectImages.Add(project.ImageSet.Images.ToList());
```

this line has an error.

> error: "Image.Add()" has some invalid arguments

actually, the code explain what do I do want. nevertheless I explain...
We have projects, projects have ImageSet(image gallery), ImageSets have Images, so...
I want to do all of Projects Images on a Image List.

Thank you for your help...

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var balikciContext = new BalikciContext())
        {
            List<Image> AllProjectImages = new List<Image>();
            foreach (var project in balikciContext.Projects.Include("ImageSet.Images").ToList())
            {
                AllProjectImages.Add(project.ImageSet.Images.ToList());
            }
            var model = new ProjectViewModel
            {
                Projects = balikciContext.Projects.ToList(),
                Images = AllProjectImages
            };
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use addrange instead of add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add()` will accept  a single image. Use `AddRange()` to add a list of images.

So you just need to change the line:

```
AllProjectImages.Add(project.ImageSet.Images.ToList());
```

To:

```
AllProjectImages.AddRange(project.ImageSet.Images.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to be using [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx), instead. [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310301(v=vs.110).aspx) is for single entries, the other mentioned is for adding collections to a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, you should use `AddRange` method.

Remember the following points while adding values to `collection`:

1. If you are only adding a small number of nodes or adding nodes infrequently, use the `Add` method.
2. However, if you need to add a large number of nodes at one time you should use `AddRange`.

Comment: Supporting what @Gul Md Ershad explained. If you have a list of items to be added into another list, you can do it by listA.AddRange(listB)

Answer (score 1):

You also don't need to convert to call `ToList()` as [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts `IEnumerable<>`

```
AllProjectImages.AddRange(project.ImageSet.Images);
```